# mocking in TestCase.setUp()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock all test methods of a `TestCase`.

My first try to use `TestCase.setUp()` did not work, since `setUp()` finishes before the test methods gets executed.

I can't mock the real test method with this inside `setUp()`:

```
with mock.patch(...):
    do_something()
```

I guess I am missing something.

How to use `mock.patch()` for all methods of a test case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`with mock.patch()` is a *context manager*, the patch is unapplied when the context ends, and the context ends at the end of the block of code.

That means that the patches are unapplied again when `setUp()` ends.

Your options are to either use `@mock.patch()` as a *class decorator* or to use the [`start` and `stop` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) on the patchers.

Using `@mock.patch()` as a class decorator has the same effect as applying it as a decorator to each and every test method:

```
@mock.patch('module.ClassName')
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # ...

    def test_one(self, class_mock):
        # ...

    def test_two(self, class_mock):
        # ...
```

Here both `test_one` and `test_two` are passed in a mock object because the `@mock.patch()` class decorator has found all test methods and decorated them.

Using the start and stop methods lets you apply and unapply patches in the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patch1 = mock.patch(...)
        self.patch1.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patch1.stop()
```

Here `patch1` is started on set-up, and stopped again when the test is torn down. This acts just like the context manager, but instead hooks into the test boundaries.

Instead of using a `tearDown`, you can also register the `patch.stop()` as a cleanup function with [`TestCase.addCleanup()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup):

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        patch1 = mock.patch(...)
        patch1.start()
        self.addCleanup(patch1.stop)
```

Comment: I've noticed that if the `@patch` decorator is applied to a "base test case" class that the test case inherits from, the patching doesn't seem to apply and the test methods aren't given the mock args. Do you know if there's a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mock.patch.start`, `mock.patch.stop`. (See [patch methods: start and stop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop)).

For example:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = mock.patch('...')
        self.MockClass = self.patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()

    def test_something(self):
        ....
```

Answer (score -1):

The most general solution, which works for all context managers is:

```python
import unittest

class TCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.cm = mock.path(...)
        self.cm.__enter__()

    def test1(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        self.cm.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Comment: There is no need to call `__enter__` and `__exit__` when there are explicit `start` and `stop` methods for just this purpose.